# How to output return value using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to output the return of this process. Anyone can help me please. Thank you.

```
$name = $false 
switch -regex -file .\bios.txt {
    '^Product Name' { $name = $true; continue }
    '^\s' { if ($name) { $_.Trim() }}
    '^\S' { if ($name) { return } Out-File .\PN.txt}

}
```

I tried that way, but the output file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Out-File .\PN.txt` command is only ever reached for (a) lines that start with a non-whitespace character (`\S`) while (b) `$name` isn't `$true`.
When it is reached, it creates an *empty* `.\PN.txt` file, due to *lack of input*.

If, perhaps, your intent was to send all output from the `switch` statement to a file, try the following:

```
$name = $false 
& { 
  switch -regex -file .\bios.txt {
    '^Product Name' { $name = $true; continue }
    '^\s' { if ($name) { $_.Trim() }}
    '^\S' { if ($name) { return } $_ }

  }
} | Out-File .\PN.txt
```